# Android: Importing a library module is causing compilation errors in my project using Gradle Plugin 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

I've been trying to figure this out for hours now.  I simply want to import my library project into my project by reference.  Importing a copy is not an option.

My settings.gradle looks like this

```
include ':app'    
include ':FunLib'    
project(':FunLib').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir,'../FunLib/library')
```

My project's build.gradle

```
implementation project(':FunLib')
```

I wish I could point to the parent directory 'FunLib', but that simply doesn't work. So I have to point to the module which is 'library'.

Because my library's root build.gradle is outside of the 'library' directory, my plugins aren't getting recognized because I set my repo urls theres.  I don't even know if it's using the right gradle version. I tried copying everything from my library root build.gradle to my project root build.gradle. Nothing has worked. Any project code that references code in my library is a compilation error.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Try to explain better the error

Comment: Gradle builds successfully, but any code in my project that references a class that is in my library project doesn't get recognized.  It's as if my project can't see my library project code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally realized that you don't really import a project.  You import a module.